# Apache ReverseProxy, SSL on Proxy, noSSL on backend-server, page manipulation

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, http

I use an Apache2 as proxy for several backend-server.
The proxy holds the Let´s-Encrypt-SSL-Certificates for all servers, http-traffic is redirected to https and then proxyed to the http-backend-servers.

Everything is running smoothly, but:

One of the backend-servers hold a Moodle-Installation. Every link points to the http-url, so browsers say, there is insecure content...

**How can I manipulate the page-content**, that is delivered from the backend via the proxy to the client?
I will have to replace every link "http://my.doimain.com/*" with "https://my.domain.com/*" within the delivered pages...

The traffic between proxy and backend-serer is http, not https.
As theses servers have no internet-access they cannot update certificates issued by let´s encrypt...

Thanks in advance
wepp

Answer (score 1):

Two possible approaches:

- Install certificates on the back-end servers so they can support https and then reconfigure the web application to run on the HTTPS back-end so that it will generate https links when referencing to itself.
  You don't need a valid certificate and can make do with a self-signed certificate on the back-end server(s) because by default mod_proxy_http  does not check the certificate (see [`SSLProxyVerify`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxyverify))
- You can rewrite the HTML pages your web application generates and rewrite any occurrence of `http://www.example.com` with [mod_proxy_html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) and the [`ProxyHTMLURLMap` Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html#proxyhtmlurlmap). A basic example would be:

  ```
  ProxyHTMLURLMap http://internal2.example.com https://www.example.com
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks HBruijn, you pointed me to the right direction.

[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/684905/proxyhtmlurlmap-not-working-in-apache2-4) is everything you need for getting this to work...
Within your VirtualHost-File add after the SSL-settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
...
ProxyPass / http://backend-server/
ProxyPreserveHost On

SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
ProxyHTMLExtended Off
ProxyHTMLInterp On
ProxyHTMLDoctype XHTML Legacy
ProxyPassReverse / http://backend-server/

ProxyHTMLURLMap http://external.server.address https://external.server.address

</VirtualHost>
```