# Former Proxy Config for Apache 2.2 Webserver not working for Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, load-balancing

On my previous server I had a **perfectly functioning Apache 2.2** Configuration.

On one hand this said perfectly functioning Apache 2.2 config has the 
purpose of **acting as a Load-Balancer** for a Web-Application running on **different Tomcats**.

After migrating to Apache 2.4 the Load Balancing part of the config is **still intact** and functioning properly.

However on the other hand after switching versions **the ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse** configuration does *not work* the way it used to.

This is how the **perfectly fine working** ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse configuration looked like in Apache 2.2:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mysubdomain.xyz.com
        ProxyRequests Off
        ...
        <Location /manager_myhostname1>
             Order deny,allow
             Deny from all
             Allow from 12.34.56.78
             ProxyPass ajp://myhostname1:8009/manager route=myhostname1
             ProxyPassReverse ajp://myhostname1:8009/manager
             SetOutputFilter proxy-html
             ProxyHTMLURLMap /manager /manager_myhostname1
        </Location>
        <Location /manager_myhostname2>
             Order deny,allow
             Deny from all
             Allow from 12.34.56.78
             ProxyPass ajp://myhostname2:8009/manager route=myhostname2
             ProxyPassReverse ajp://myhostname2:8009/manager
             SetOutputFilter proxy-html
             ProxyHTMLURLMap /manager /manager_myhostname2
        </Location>
        <Location /manager_myhostname3>
             Order deny,allow
             Deny from all
             Allow from 12.34.56.78
             ProxyPass ajp://myhostname3:8009/manager route=myhostname3
             ProxyPassReverse ajp://myhostname3:8009/manager
             SetOutputFilter proxy-html
             ProxyHTMLURLMap /manager /manager_myhostname3
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The above part of the config basically facilitates that the **Tomcat Manager Pages** of the individual hosts of the Load-Balancing-Cluster are **accessible** through these URLs:

```
- mysubdomain.xyz.com/manager_myhostname1
- mysubdomain.xyz.com/manager_myhostname2
- mysubdomain.xyz.com/manager_myhostname3
```

To **rule out common errors** while migrating from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 I have rewritten the above config like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mysubdomain.xyz.com
        ProxyRequests Off
        ...
        <Location /manager_myhostname1>
             Require ip 12.34.56.78
             ProxyPass ajp://myhostname1:8009/manager route=myhostname1
             ProxyPassReverse ajp://myhostname1:8009/manager
             SetOutputFilter proxy-html
             ProxyHTMLURLMap /manager /manager_myhostname1
        </Location>
        <Location /manager_myhostname2>
             Require ip 12.34.56.78
             ProxyPass ajp://myhostname2:8009/manager route=myhostname2
             ProxyPassReverse ajp://myhostname2:8009/manager
             SetOutputFilter proxy-html
             ProxyHTMLURLMap /manager /manager_myhostname2
        </Location>
        <Location /manager_myhostname3>
             Require ip 12.34.56.78
             ProxyPass ajp://myhostname3:8009/manager route=myhostname3
             ProxyPassReverse ajp://myhostname3:8009/manager
             SetOutputFilter proxy-html
             ProxyHTMLURLMap /manager /manager_myhostname3
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But these changes were of no avail.
When accessing the URL `mysubdomain.xyz.com/manager_myhostname1` the Apache gives me the following **error page**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>404 Not Found</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Not Found</h1>
        <p>The requested URL /manager/ was not found on this server.</p>
        <hr>
        <address>Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at mysubdomain.xyz.com Port 443</address>
    </body>
</html>
```

The **same error** takes place for the other two URLs.

It seems that **no matter** which part after the first forward slash comes in, it gets rewritten into `/manager` instead of `/manager_myhostname1` (or analogously `/manager_myhostname2`, `/manager_myhostname3`).

1. Which crucial part have I **missed** during the migration?
2. Are there any **obvious misconfigurations** in the above config?
3. Why is the **ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse** configuration not working anymore, so that I can access the **Tomcat manager pages** of the individual tomcat hosts referenced by `/manager_myhostname1` etc. like I could on Apache 2.2?

---

EDIT:

I have already searched through these sources and tried different things out:

- [ProxyHTMLURLMap not working in apache2.4](https://serverfault.com/questions/684905/proxyhtmlurlmap-not-working-in-apache2-4)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431090/proxyhtml-to-rewrite-url
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html#proxyhtmlurlmap

---

EDIT for @Gerald Schneider **first** comment:

I **apologize** for not using a **CLI tool** to do the request:

```
myuser@myhomecomputer ~ $ wget -S https://mysubdomain.xyz.com/manager_myhostname1
--2019-05-14 15:59:27--  https://mysubdomain.xyz.com/manager_myhostname1
Resolving mysubdomain.xyz.com (mysubdomain.xyz.com)... 57.5.103.87
Connecting to mysubdomain.xyz.com (mysubdomain.xyz.com)|57.5.103.87|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 302 Found
  Date: Tue, 14 May 2019 13:59:27 GMT
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Location: /manager/
  Content-Length: 0
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
Location: /manager/ [following]
--2019-05-14 15:59:27--  https://mysubdomain.xyz.com/manager/
Reusing existing connection to mysubdomain.xyz.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  Date: Tue, 14 May 2019 13:59:27 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
  Content-Length: 283
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
2019-05-14 15:59:27 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

---

EDIT for  @Gerald Schneider **second** comment:

I have added `ProxyHTMLEnable On`, but it has **no effect** whatsoever, as the ouptut of the wget is exactly as above.

---

EDIT after activating **logging** for the `proxy_html` module, which is responsible for the mapping of proxied urls. The log now contains the following lines:

```
[Wed May 15 10:35:01.671633 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 26190] proxy_util.c(2418): [client 12.34.567.890:60476] AH00947: connected /manager to myhostname1:8009
[Wed May 15 10:35:01.672047 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 26190] proxy_util.c(2884): AH02824: HTTP: connection established with 192.168.0.3:8009 (myhostname1)
[Wed May 15 10:35:01.672083 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 26190] proxy_util.c(3051): AH00962: HTTP: connection complete to 192.168.0.3:8009 (myhostname1)
[Wed May 15 10:35:01.673241 2019] [proxy_http:trace3] [pid 26190] mod_proxy_http.c(1376): [client 12.34.567.890:60476] Status from backend: 302
[Wed May 15 10:35:01.673319 2019] [proxy_http:trace3] [pid 26190] mod_proxy_http.c(1647): [client 12.34.567.890:60476] start body send
[Wed May 15 10:35:01.673339 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 26190] proxy_util.c(2171): AH00943: http: has released connection for (myhostname1)
[Wed May 15 10:35:01.673351 2019] [proxy_html:trace1] [pid 26190] mod_proxy_html.c(827): [client 12.34.567.890:60476] No content-type; bailing out of proxy-html filter
```

The connection to the proxied server seems successful, but the last line says `No content-type; bailing out of proxy-html filter`, indicating that any Directives from the `proxy_html` module are **not applied**.

Comment: Can you please try to run the request with wget or curl and post the output including headers (for example `wget -S https://mysubdomain.xyz.com/manager_myhostname1`? I have the suspicion that your backend server serves a redirect, since they are configured as  `/manager` and that's where you end.

Comment: Do you have `ProxyHTMLEnable On` somewhere in your config? It's off by default.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my configuration to this:

```
<Location /manager_myhostname1>
    Require ip 12.34.56.78
    ProxyPass ajp://myhostname1:8009/manager route=myhostname1
    ProxyPassReverse ajp://myhostname1:8009/manager
    SetOutputFilter proxy-html
    ProxyHTMLURLMap /manager/ /manager_myhostname1/
</Location>
```

Differences are the **ending slashes** in the `ProxyHTMLURLMap`. (analogously for `manager_myhostname2` and `manager_myhostname3`)

Now I can access the individual manager pages with these URLs:

- https://mysubdomain.xyz.com/manager_myhostname1/html
- https://mysubdomain.xyz.com/manager_myhostname2/html
- https://mysubdomain.xyz.com/manager_myhostname3/html

Seems like the proxying gets destroyed when Apache gets the redirect from the `/manager` page to the `/manager/html` page. That redirect is something that Tomcat does internally, but can't communicate to the Apache.